# JavaFX - make elements with weight_sum like on Android

Tags: java, javafx

- I have a full screen application in javaFX.
- I would like to have 8 equal sized "tiles" in 2 rows.
- With TilePane the problem is that I can just make a suggestion about
  the number of rows
- GridPane makes sizes dinamically

The best would be to use it somehow like the layout_weight on android. Do you know what is the easiest way to do it?

I prefer FXML!

Comment: Use a grid pane with the column constraints set (see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)), or maybe a [`TilePane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html)

Comment: @James_D Thank you, this one helps me. I use GridPane now. How can I reach my GridPane that I made in .fxml? I have a MyController class. Inside that: @ FXML private GridPane gridPane;
Now: if I say gridPane.getColumnConstraits()... it is a null pointer exception. (I think it is beacuse it the GridPane is not existing yet). So where should I reach that?